# Monodevelop.ошибка создания целевого объекта

Tags: c#, monodevelop

Переношу проект с# window в `monodevelop`. Но выходит ошибка при компиляции 
ошибка создания целевого объекта `LinkEmbeddableAssemblies`:

> метаданные элемента должны ссылаться на имя элемента% (ItemName.MetadataName).

Что нужно делать в данном случае? В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте подключенные сборки (assemblies) двойным щелчком на пункте "ссылки" слева. Там должны быть выбраны все сборки, соответствующие вашим операторам using